Diffraction when the wavefront is not parallel to the plane
I am studying Feynman's chapter on the origin of the index of the refractive index (see this link).
If I am not mistaken, what he does is to prove that when a wave enters a medium (modelled as a succession of close, parallel planes full of oscillating electrons), the wavefronts move at a lower speed, assuming they are parallel to the planes of the medium.
Indeed, the proof relies on the computation made in the previous chapter (see section 30–7 The field of a plane of oscillating charges on this link) where the source is assumed to be a point located far away, so we can assume that the incoming wave is plane wave with wavefronts parallel to the plane.
I tried to adapt the proof but the resulting integral looks much more complicated.
Indeed, if $D$ is the distance from a point $y$ from the plane of oscillating particles, the original integral is $\int_{plane} \frac{1}{d(x,y)} e^{-i\omega \frac{1}{c}d(x,y)}dx = \int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{r}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{D^2+r^2}} e^{-i\omega \frac{1}{c}\sqrt{D^2+r^2}}d\theta dr$ which can be easily solved with a change of variables.
If the wavefronts of the incoming wave are not parallel to the plane, then we have to add a factor $e^{-i\omega \frac{1}{c}\langle \overrightarrow{x_0 x}, \vec{v}\rangle}$ to the integral, where $\vec{v}$ denotes a unit vector orthogonal to the wavefronts of the incoming wave.
I am a bit disappointed, because I think that the book, at this point, only proves Snell's law for a zero angle of incidence.
Am I missing something important here?

My advice is to get an actual textbook. The Feynman lectures are amusing but not the place to start learning physics for the first time.

If you have a reference in mind that works out the thing I am interested in, feel free to post it as an answer and I’ll award the bounty to you :)

I can do that. But to be clear, are you just looking for formal derivation of Snells' law?

Yes, yes. But something that follows more or less the same path as Feynman, that is, find out that the wave, after going through a plane of charged particles, gets a small phase shift. Actually, I was looking at the videos of 3blue1brown and wanted to fill in the missing details.

Oh, and to add: the more mathematical the reference is, the happier I am.

You really don't need a lot of math to explain snells law, and while the 3Blue1Brown explanation is a good way to think about it, it is not a good way to derive it. Snell's law is nothing more than applying boundary conditions at an interface. You do not need to understand the origin of the index of refraction or even how it works. You just need Maxwell's equations and an interface. I can derive it for you the way Jacksons EM does it but I don't think you'll be satisfied, however this derivation is the universally accepted one.

This is how you derive Snell's law: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/3-024-electronic-optical-and-magnetic-properties-of-materials-spring-2013/480e12b984eb21a5e88b8ee5cc051ef8_MIT3_024S13_2012lec22.pdf
This is how it is typically derived in any EM class. Any EM book (Jackson, Zangwill, Neyfeh) is going to do it just this way.
If you want a more medieval explanation, you'll want either Fermat's principal or Huygen-Fresnel's principal.

In fact, I think that what I am trying to prove is precisely a proof of Condition 2 in the document.

The BC about electric displacement and $\sigma$?

If BC means « boundary condition », then, yes, I guess.

This is just an application of Gauss law at the boundary; proof of this will simply be proof of Gauss' law.

In fact, I am suspecting that the precise definition of « interface » already assumes what I want to prove.

So even if your wave fronts are "parallel" to the plane, if they have a phase that varies over one dimension of the plane, they are in effect incoming or outgoing at an angle. So this is still consistent with the idea of a plane of oscillating charges, where the phase of the waves have to match the phase of the charges.
So at the end of the day, it's just a more complex way of describing plane waves at an angle, with a boundary matching condition that respects the phase per unit length over the surface.
